# p:selectOneMenu validation fails

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces SelectOneMenu as follows:

```
    <p:selectOneMenu id="inviteAbleRoleSelect"
            styleClass="dropDownSelector"
            value="#{invitationManagedBean.selectedRole}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{invitationManagedBean.inviteAbleRoles}"
                var="role"
                itemValue="#{role}"
                itemLabel="#{localized[role.concat('RoleName')]}">
                </f:selectItems>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

And the following JavaScript called on complete:

```
function handleUserInvitationRequest(xhr,status,args){
            if (args.validationFailed) {
                jQuery('#userInviterDialog').effect("shake", {
                    times : 3
                }, 70);
            } else {
                userInviterDialogVar.hide();
                refreshInvitedUserList();
            }
        }
```

When I submit the form, I get an ajax POST with the correctly filled form, but when it calls the handler, the validationFailed is true, even if the element is not required. Also the changes coming in the ajax response sets the select to an empty select.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a totally lame fault...
The bean was `@RequestScoped` ...
At least `@ViewScoped` is required.

Answer (score 1):

If your role is not a String or any primitive type, then you are probably getting `Validation Error: Value is not valid`, therefor you need to implement a Converter for your Role Entity/Object, it would be something like this.

```
@FacesConverter("roleConverter")
public class RoleConverter implements Converter {


   @Override
   public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, 
                                 UIComponent component, 
                                 String value) {
       //prepare your datasource ex. EJB .. etc
       if (value.trim().equals("")) {
           return null;
       } else {
           Role role = datasource.findById(value); //get role from database
           retun role;
       }

   }

   @Override
   public String getAsString(FacesContext context, 
                                 UIComponent component, 
                                 Object value)   {
       if (value == null || value.equals("")) {
           return "";
       } else {
           return String.valueOf(((Role) value).getId());
       }
   }

 }
```

*selectOneMenu*

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="inviteAbleRoleSelect"
        styleClass="dropDownSelector"
        value="#{invitationManagedBean.selectedRole}" converter="roleConverter">
            <f:selectItems value="#{invitationManagedBean.inviteAbleRoles}"
            var="role"
            itemValue="#{role}"
            itemLabel="#{localized[role.concat('RoleName')]}">
            </f:selectItems>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

And you need to make sure that your Role implements equals and hashcode.